When is the function $f$ differentiable over irrationals?

Consider the function
$$
\operatorname{f}\left( x \right) \equiv
\begin{cases}
 0,\quad \,\,\,x\in \mathbb{Q} ^c\\[2mm]
 a_{n},\quad x = {\displaystyle\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}}\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $\left(m,n\right) = 1$.


My question is: When is $\operatorname{f}$ differentiable $\mbox{over}\ \mathbb{Q}^c$ ?.

My attempts:

Classical Riemann function $\left(\mbox{i.e.}\ a_{n} = 1/n\right)$ seem to fail, and $a_{n} = 1/n^{2}$ does not work either.
By Liouville's approximation theorem I managed to show that the function is derivative over algebraic numbers provided
$$
n^{k}\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert \to 0\quad \mbox{for some}\quad k\ge 2
$$
I wonder if there are more general results.

Thanks in advance.

For many results and references, see my 13 December 2006 sci.math post Differentiability of the Ruler Function.

The problem is that for an rational number $\frac m n$, $\vert\frac m n - x\vert$ may be arbitrary small. That means that I do not hope to find a generic expression for $a_n$ valid for any $x\in\Bbb Q^c$.

@SergeBallesta If we want $\left|\frac{m}{n}-x\right|$ small enough, $n$ has to be big enough because for a upper bound $N$, there are only limited rational numbers whose $n$ is smaller than $N$.

@JCQ: what I mean is that for an irrational number, its distance to a rational $\frac m n$ (n fixed) is a priori evenly distributed in the interval $]0; \frac 1 n[$. So $\vert\frac m n - x\vert$ can be arbitrary smaller than $\frac 1 n$.

@SergeBallesta Sorry I am still confused. When $n$ is fixed, how can $|\frac{m}{n}-x|$ be arbitrarily smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$? Consider $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\in(0,1)$: if $n$ is fixed, there are only no more than $n-1$ rational numbers $\frac{m}{n}\in(0,1)$, so there must be a lower bound for $|\frac{m}{n}-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)|$.
